# Moving object from vector A to B in 2d environment with in increments of percents

Tags: javascript, vector, linear-interpolation

I know coordinates of vectors A and B. How can I count first point between these two vectors? First vector X is 1% of the distance between vectors A and B. So first I will move object in vector A 1% closer to vector B. So I need to calculate vector X that is new vector for object, until it reaches vector B.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want [lerp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerp_%28computing%29)ing. For reference, the basic formula is:

`x = A + t * (B - A)`

Where t is between 0 and 1. (Anything outside that range makes it an *extra*polation.)

Check that `x = A` when `t = 0` and `x = B` when `t = 1`.

Note that my answer doesn't mention vectors or 2D.

Answer (score 14):

Turning [aib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198217/moving-object-form-vector-a-to-b-in-2d-environment-with-in-increments-of-precents/6198395#6198395) into code:

```
function lerp(a, b, t) {
    var len = a.length;
    if(b.length != len) return;

    var x = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        x.push(a[i] + t * (b[i] - a[i]));
    return x;
}

var A = [1,2,3];
var B = [2,5,6];

var X = lerp(A, B, 0.01);
```