# Bounce a ball from one point to another - Vector and Acceleration

Tags: javascript, math, physics, game-physics

I have a ball which drops to a point, from which it should bounce and reach another point.

My ball starts with an acceleration towards the first point, hits the point and bounces off to the left side. What I want is the velocity & acceleration applied to the ball after hitting the first point, so it both has a bouncing effect, and reaches it's destination (doesn't go offside, like the bright trail).

I have the linear vector between points, coordinates of points and angle between them.

[image: Explanation]

Comment: What's your question? Where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: some similar questions worth looking: [cannon ball trajectory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174961/2521214) , [Bouncing Ball](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20017455/2521214)

Answer (score 2):

First we figure out how long it will take to get from the higher point to the lower point by solving for `t`:

> at<sup>2</sup> + v<sub>iy</sub>t = dy

Then we take `t` and use it for our lateral velocity:

> v<sub>x</sub> = dx / t

Once you have the lateral velocity, just slice time up as finely as you like and move the ball to each calculated point in turn.

Comment: Could you please add some details on the math? I don't get what a in at² and the indices on v mean. I would like to try it.

Comment: @stacker `a.t^2+v(iy)=dy` is y axis equation of the bounced movement `a` is local forcefield (gravity) acceleration (usually `-9.81m.s^-2`), `v(iy)` is the incident speed in y axis after hitting the ground the first time, `t` is time from the first bounce and `dy` is the ground line size in y axis only `a,v,dy` are knowns `t` is unknown you need to solve that quadratic equation and the resulting positive `t` is time the ball need to hit the second bounce point .the rest should be clear ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a full blown physics simulation you could fake this by a linear interpolation (lerp) from the start point to end-point.

See [Moving object from vector A to B in 2d environment with in increments of percents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198217/moving-object-from-vector-a-to-b-in-2d-environment-with-in-increments-of-percent) for lerp in java script.

Change the coordinate pointing upwards (y or z) depending on the coordinate system you use. 
While t is animated from 0..1:

```
 var relativeHeight = Math.Sin( t * Math.PI ) * curveAmplitude;
 posy = orgPosy + relativeHeight;
```